# Enlarge Matlab figure control handles?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Can I make the "control handles" in MATLAB bigger?
They used to be nice and big, but now they're so small I simply can't click on them!

[image]

Matlab R2014b 64-bit on Ubuntu 14.04

You'll see they're the **miniscule** blue dots at the 8 corners/edges of the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it eventually: I had to increase my default figure DPI setting, like this:

```
get(0)

     CallbackObject: []
           Children: []
      CurrentFigure: []
 FixedWidthFontName: 'Courier New'
   HandleVisibility: 'on'
   MonitorPositions: [3x4 double]
             Parent: []
    PointerLocation: [673 377]
        ScreenDepth: 24
ScreenPixelsPerInch: 30
         ScreenSize: [1 1 2560 1600]
  ShowHiddenHandles: 'off'
                Tag: ''
               Type: 'root'
              Units: 'pixels'
           UserData: []


set(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch',90)
```

Which gives sensible-sized handles.